# npm install with several package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I have a project that has a submodule which also has a submodule, each of them (root & submodule_1 & submodule_2) have a `package.json`.

Here is how I scaffolded my project :

```
|root
----|node_modules
----|package.json
----|someFolder
----|submodule_1
-------- |package.json
-------- |someFolder
-------- |submodule_2
------------ |package.json
------------ |someFolder
```

Is it possible to precise to npm to install each dependencies in the root `node_modules` ? I don’t want submodule_1 and submodule_2 to be dependencies, I just want the packages.json to be installed in the root `node_modules`.

If it is possible, how can I achieve this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: npm will install duplicated dependencies in root node_modules if all of them are in same version. You can read more about packages deduplication here https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe You can also do this manually by calling `npm dedupe`

Comment: you can install the dependencies flat with `yarn install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after lots of digging into npm docs and all, I realized that setting submodule_1 as a [local dependency](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths) and submodule_2 as a dependency of submodule_1 was doing exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

sorry it is not possible to precise to npm to install each dependencies in the root

Answer (score 0):

All dependencies and subdependencies are installed in root `node_modules` by default, only duplicated dependencies/subdependencies are exception.

`npm` will install duplicated dependencies in root `node_modules` if all of them are/can be installed in same version.

You can read more about packages deduplication here https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dedupe

You can also do this manually by calling `npm dedupe`

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: The thing is that when I run `npm install`, it doesn't install dependencies from submodule_1 and submodule_2's package.json. Is there something I need to precise in the root package.json ?

Comment: Hello. How about the opposite of this ? I want npm to install every package.json packages in their own node_modules folder, instead of root folder. Is it possible ?